# No method declared with Objective c selector 'scale'

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, selector

I'm currently following the Stanford lecture on iOS development. I want create a pinch gesture that can enlarge or reduce the size of the smiley face. Here is the original code:

```
faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: "scale:"))
```

However, Xcode complained that "`no method declared with Objective c selector 'scale'`".

I followed its suggestion by replace `"scale:" with Selector("scale:")` but it still display the same error message.

I did a bit of research online and found out that from swift 2.2, the syntax for selector has changed to `#selector(MyClass.methodName)`, so I changed the line of code to

```
faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: #selector(FaceView.scale)))
```

This time, no error message is displayed, but when I run the project and tried to enlarge or reduce the smiley face in simulator, it does not change size at all.

Comment: I think there is parameter in scale: function ... so swift 2.2 syntax would be `#selector(FaceView.scale(_:))`

Comment: I have added _: to the selector but pinch still doesn't work. Sorry if my question sounds silly to you, i'm just a beginner at this. Could you think of any other possibilities? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: nothing silly about this ... now check with breakpoints ... is method called or not

Comment: I think the method is been called. I run the project again, and something strange happened. When I pinched, enlarged and released the mouse, the smiley face does not change its size. but afterwards, if I press down the mouse and drag up or down, the smiley face suddenly become enlarged. I think the pinch is working, is just that the simulator does not show the changes in size during pinching. Its puzzling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like something changed since the last release.

You have been suggested to use 
`#selector(MyClass.methodName)` as the documentation does so this is the correct syntax

In the case of your stanford lecture you have a class on the View called FaceView with a method called *scale*.

So MyClass is FaceView and the selector will be `#selector(FaceView.scale)`

As well the final line will be 
`faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: #selector(FaceView.scale)))`

Hope that I helped ya, I just faced with the same problem ;)